# Does docker have a windows container to build windows applications on?

Tags: docker, electron

I am on a mac but want to build my application on a windows image. Is this possible with docker? If so what image do I need to use?

The reason I need to build the application on windows is for the code signing and binary building of electron. If this is not possible please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since docker is not meant to be a UI for users (though it `can` be); images for Windows 7, 8, 10, et al are not available. However, [Windows Server Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/) IS available via the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com).

If you simply need a x86 Win environment to build the application that should do the trick. If you need a full GUI, go [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or other virtualization tech. Docker containers are meant for single process isolation, ever see windows run only 1 process?

Hope this helps!

Update: It IS possible to run GUI applications via Docker; at least on a Linux host. http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Update2: It is now possible to run Windows applications (CLI or GUI) via Docker: [here](https://blog.sixeyed.com/how-to-dockerize-windows-applications/) and [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-containerize-windows-desktop-applications-with-gui-using-docker/50543) has information regarding the process.

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to build the application, no GUI.

Comment: We should mention: this will not work on a Mac, unless you are in a Windows VM. Windows Docker Images will only run on Windows Server and on Docker Desktop on Windows 10 (with Windows Container mode enabled)